# How to get hostname of instance through a tag

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have setup a tag (monitored : true) for 500 instances. Now depending upon this tag I need to get the hostname of each and every instance which has this tag. Also I think we need to do pagination right? If so what would be good approach while coding using AWS SDK JAVA API. Please also suggest what would be the correct method to use for this by invoking AWS SDK JAVA API.

As right now I am able to pull instanceIds of instances which ever has this tag but not following  pagination through reservations. Please help if atleast you know how to get hostname with an instanceId.

The code I tried to get instance Id

```
 escribeInstancesRequest request = new.    DescribeInstancesRequest();
 List<String> valuesT1 = new.    ArrayList<String>();
 valuesT1.add("my-keypair-name");
 Filter filter = new Filter("key-name", valuesT1);

 DescribeInstancesResult result =      ec2.describeInstances(request.withFilters(filter));

 List<Reservation> reservations = result.getReservations();

 for (Reservation reservation : reservations)      {
     List<Instance> instances = reservation.getInstances();

     for (Instance instance : instances) {

         System.out.println(instance.getInstanceId());


     }
 }
```

Comment: Please do add the code that you've tried.

Comment: @KaranShah Hey added code

Comment: @KaranShah do u have any idea?